# Помогите найти ошибку, загрузка идет только тогда, когда в массиве цифры

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Все работает отлично когда в массиве цифры, но как только появляется текст, то перестает работать, что я упустил?

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5); // если $array = array('один','два','три','четыре','пять'); то в БД не загружает
```

`$query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (text) VALUES (" . implode("), (", $array) . ")";
$res = mysql_query($query);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы упустили одинарные кавычки. Вот так запрос попробуйте смормировать

```
$query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (text) VALUES ('" . implode("'), ('", $array) . "')";
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас проверю

Comment: блин, спасибо большое, совсем забыл про кавычки, очень стыдно. 
Вам огромное спасибо.